# how can i run an html form button on page load?

Tags: asp.net

i want to run the submit button when the page loads

Here is my form, it redirect to paypal and i want to run on page load

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server" action="<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PayPalSubmitUrl"] %>" 
    method="post" >
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart"/>
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PayPalEmailAddress"] %>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Shopping_Cart"/>
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1"  value="<%=Session["Total"].ToString() %>" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR" />
<input type="submit" id="submit" runat="server"   value="PayPal"  />
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you could use javascript since this doesn't appear to use a server call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use some Jquery and Javascript to submit the form as soon as the document is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
document.forms["form1"].submit(); 
});
```

Comment: Use some Jquery and Javascript to submit the form as soon as the document is ready.  


You need  reference to jquery library in your code.

`<script type='text/javascript'               src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.js'></script>`

Then in your html after your form add this

`<script type='text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() {
document.forms["form1"].submit(); 
});</script>`

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function callButtonClickEvent() {
        document.forms["form1"].submit(); 
    }
</script>